# why the getnow() method is undefined for the type HttpClient?

Tags: testing, microservices, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

```
@Test
  public void serverIsStarted(TestContext context) {
      final Async async = context.async(); // <-- create the Async instance

      vertx.createHttpClient().getnow(8081, "localhost", "/inexistent", response -> {
          context.assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());

          async.complete();  // <-- signal this test can now terminate
      });
  }
 //   });
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are upgrading from Vert.x 3 to Vert.x 4?

In Vert.x 4, the `HttpClient` API has been reworked. You should do this:

```
client.request(HttpMethod.GET, "/inexistent", ar1 -> {
  if (ar1.succeeded()) {
    HttpClientRequest request = ar1.result();
    request.send(ar2 -> {
      if (ar2.succeeded()) {
        HttpClientResponse response = ar2.result();
        context.assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
        async.complete();  // <-- signal this test can now terminate
      }
    });
  }
});
```